# How to refresh page on click (ionic v4)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Trying to refresh a page when the user deletes data. Some `Html` elements on the page automatically update, but the main app component holds onto the old data until the page is manually refreshed.

`ionViewWillEnter()` no longer works as illustrated in this example: [How to refresh page in ionic 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54627442/how-to-refresh-page-in-ionic-4)

I tried using `ngOnInit()` instead, but that didn't work. I've also tried ChangeDetectorRef, but no joy.

**typescript**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'

public contentId: any;
public content: any;

constructor(private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  ...
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.fetchData();
}

fetchData() {
  ...
  this.database.get(contentId).subscribe( content => {
    this.content = content[0];
 });
}

deleteData() {
  this.content.delete(id);
  this.changeRef.detectChanges();
}
```

**Html**

```
<app-content *ngIf="contentId" [pageContent]="contentId"></app-content>
```

**data from** `this.content`

```
{
 id: 'contentId',
 text: 'some text',
 author: 'username',
 uid: 'userId'
}
```

Comment: why do you need a refresh when the item is deleted? is it a requirement or are you trying to cover up something with the page refresh?

Comment: it looks like you are binding `[pageContent]="contentId"` - where is `content` getting involved?

Answer (score 0):

Try with **`ionViewWillEnter`**

```
  ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.fetchData();
  }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Need the page to auto-refresh when the user clicks a button to delete content.

Comment: you are already using detectChanges, that should bind the changes. can you assign the content back to the binding array

Comment: It should, yes. Can you explain below how to assign the content back to the binding array, please? Put answer below...

Comment: post the output of JSON.stringify(this.content) and what is the value of id?

Comment: An array from firebase containing the content to be populated onscreen

Comment: IKR, could you please post the array content. thats where the problem is

Comment: can you post entire code? how does contentId gets updated?